# Register Class For Table View Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, cell, registerclass

I would like to ask when do we need to register class for tableview cell and when do we not to. I am very confused.Can anyone answer me ?

```
        tableView.registerClass(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Comment: When you have custom cell in a seperate xib other than the tableview itself :) you have to register the class :) If you are using storyboard and have prototype cell in tableview storyboard itself you don't have to register :) Thats all :)

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot